# treeview checkbox onchecked with if command issue

Tags: reactjs

This is my sample. Its working without issue.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

    return (
        <CheckboxTree
            nodes={listItems}
            iconsClass="fa5"
            checked={checked}
            data={classData}
            onCheck={setChecked}
        /> 
    );
}
```

But Now I need to add onchecked command like below.

```
onCheck={(nodes, node) => {
                
                const checkState = node.checked ? true : false;
                setChecked(checkState);
                if (node.parent.length > 0) {
                       classCode = node.parent;
                       viewRequired = node.viewRequired;
                       formatRequired = node.formatRequired; 
                       }
                }}
```

Now my checkbox is not cheked when I check it. But My data is setting without  any issue. (claassCode, viewRequired.. .). Is there a way to fix this issue. Please give suggestions.

[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-treeview-1zwd3w?file=/src/components/Widget.js)

Comment: Can you please share a full code example using code sandbox or another online IDE? Thanks

Comment: @SahilArdeshna please check https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-treeview-1zwd3w?file=/src/components/Widget.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add node value in checked states. The CheckboxTree component will take checked state values and display them accordingly in the checkbox tree.

This function will update the checked state

```
const updateCheckedState = (node) => {
    const childValues = [];
    const isParent = node.isParent;

    if (isParent) {
      node.children.forEach((child) => {
        childValues.push(child.value);
      });
    }

    const updatedValues = isParent ? childValues : [node.value];

    if (node.checked) {
      if (node.parent.length > 0) {
        classCode = node.parent;
        //many values are there to get
      }

      setChecked([...checked, ...updatedValues]);
    } else {
      const filteredChecks = checked.filter((check) => {
        return !updatedValues.includes(check);
      });

      setChecked(filteredChecks);
    }
  };
```

updated CheckboxTree component

```
<CheckboxTree
      iconsClass="fa5"
      nodes={nodes}
      checked={checked}
      expanded={expanded}
      onCheck={(nodes, node) => {
        updateCheckedState(node);
      }}
      onExpand={(expanded) => setExpanded(expanded)}
    />
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-glitter-6p9uyu?file=/src/components/Widget.js)

Thanks